# bootstrap3 - hide.bs.dropdown function firing regardless of .click definition? ..with fiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

Have a setup where a .click event that calls a setRead() function when the dropdown-menu closes, which triggers an ajax call.

Right now, for some reason the setRead() function is being called regardless of the .click definition.. http://jsfiddle.net/N2v9S/6/

setRead() should only be called when .markRead is clicked, not .markedRead

Here's the HTML (it involves handlebars templating, where the value is a different id for each btn):

```
<div class="thisness">
    <div class="exterior">
      <input type="hidden" name="storyID" id="storyID" class="storyID" value="id1" />
    <div class="interior">
      <div class="btn-group dropdown markRead">
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.btn-group(dropdown)-->
    </div></div><!--/.interior/.exterior-->
    ...
</div><!--/.thisness-->
```

Here's the Javascript/jQuery:

```
function setRead(id, markedRead, datetimeRead) {

  var AjaxReadData = {
      id : id,
      markedRead : markedRead,
      datetimeRead : datetimeRead
  };

  // make an ajax call
  alert('ajax of ' + id + ' markedRead: ' + markedRead + ' at ' + datetimeRead);

  console.log(AjaxReadData.id + " message marked read: " + AjaxReadData.markedRead);

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".thisness").on("click", ".markRead", function () {

        var datetimeRead = new Date(); // setting the datetime when read

        console.log('markRead clicked');

        var $this = $(this),
            $that = $(this).closest('.exterior').find('.glyphicon-unchecked');

        markedRead = true;

        $that.removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked').addClass('glyphicon-check');
        console.log('now checked icon');

        $this.removeClass('markRead').addClass('markedRead');
        console.log('now markedRead class');

        var id = $(this).closest('.exterior').find( ".storyID" ).val();
        console.log(id);

        console.log('ready for ajax of ' + id + ' markedRead: ' + markedRead + ' at ' + datetimeRead);

        // when .markRead (now .markedRead) dropdown closes      
        $(".thisness").on("hide.bs.dropdown", $this , function () {
          console.log('ajax of ' + id + ' markedRead: ' + markedRead + ' at ' + datetimeRead);
          setRead(id, markedRead, datetimeRead);
        })

    });

}); // doc is ready
```

Also tested a .when and .then jQuery promise, but this actually runs before the dropdown-menu is hidden?

```
$.when( $(".thisness").on("hide.bs.dropdown", $this) ).then(function () {
  console.log('ajax of ' + id + ' markedRead: ' + markedRead + ' at ' + datetimeRead);
    setRead(id, markedRead, datetimeRead);
})
```

Comment: If you say: ` $that = $(this).closest('.exterior').find('.glyphicon-unchecked');` and then you are checking `if ($that.hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked')){...}`  - Isn't this always going to be true?

Comment: @blurfus Ah yes.. good point.. even so, the issue (as shown in the fiddle) is really that setRead is called even when the .markedRead dropdown is clicked..?

Comment: @blurfus removed the redundancy, and clarified the question.. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are attaching an event handler.  So, it's not like it goes away outside the if statement, it's been attached.  Do a test, manually set one of the glyphicons to check and run the page.  You'll see that even after clicking the checked icon, and selecting from it's dropdown, setRead() doesn't run.

Use the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function instead of on().

```
$(".thisness").one("hide.bs.dropdown", $this , function () {
    console.log('ajax of ' + id + ' markedRead: ' + markedRead + ' at ' + datetimeRead);
    setRead(id, markedRead, datetimeRead);
})
```

Comment: very interesting.. appreciate the explanation.. where should the off() be placed exactly?

Comment: I take it back, the easiest way is to use the one() function instead of the on() function.  That will attach the handler for just one event. I'll update my answer.